# how to get list of files in dropbox shared folder

Tags: macos, dropbox-api

I want to update my app's database with dropbox. 
It should download some files and db file located in specific folder in my Dropbox account.

The algorithm is something like this:
1. App makes request to shared folder and downloads db by specified name(like myapp.db)
2. App reads db, get list of file to download and looking for them in shared folder
3. App downloads this files from shared folder

Is it possible? I don't want to show any authentication requests to user, and actually user can't be authenticated since he just get access to shared folder in my account.

Can I do this with Dropbox API?

platform is os x

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the Dropbox API to do this. Just put the public URL for `myapp.db` into the app, and in `myapp.db` put all the URLs of the files. Then you're not even tied to Dropbox, since all you need is public URLs. Note that Dropbox has bandwidth limits, so if this is a heavily-used app, you might want to put these on a more appropriate host like S3. Using direct URLs gives you the flexibility to change hosts in the future.